# Windows CE Application development Server SQL connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, windows-ce

I'm developing an application for windows CE machine and the .Net framework is  2.0. I've no idea which reference I should use to connect the application with the SQL database in server. The library *Linq*  doesn't seems supporting versions below 3.5.

But how can I achieve it in an alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use standard ADO.NET and SqlClient ([SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.80).aspx), SqlCommand etc.) - but you may have issues connecting to newer SQL Server versions